# Making nested namespaces in a single Django 2 app

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to create nested namespaces in my application in Django 2.
I'm aware that I am required to use `app_name` in my `urls.py` file, but my question is, how would I do it if I wish to nest multiple namespaces in a single app?

My app is called `account` and I wish to be able to reverse the following:
`account:index`, `account:edit:index`, `account:create:index`, `account:edit:email:index` and so on. How would I approach this in Django 2?

Here is a simplified version of what I have tried so far, without success.

In my account.urls file

```
app_name = 'account'

email_url = [
    path('', edit_email, name='index')
]

edit_url = [
    path('', edit, name='index'),
    path('email/' include(email_url, namespace='email'))
]

create_url = [
    path('', create, name='index'),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),

    # edit
    path('edit/', include(edit_url, namespace='edit')),

    # create
    path('create/', include(create_url, namespace='create')),
]
```

In my root urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

Comment: you want to do reverse('account:edit') ? or reverse('account:edit:some_function')?

Comment: @OjasKale I wish to be able to reverse the following inside the same app: `account:edit:index` and `account:create:index` and `account:index` all as different URLs. Where index is the `name` of an URL inside a url group with a namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the include [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#include)

> include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)

pattern_list followed by **app_namespace**

You have to define app_namespace, not namespace

I've done a similar project you did, and it works.

```
# top level urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

---

```
# accounts/urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import index, create_index, edit_index
app_name = 'accounts'

create_url =[
    path('index/', create_index, name='index'),
]

edit_url =[
    path('index/', edit_index, name='index'),
]


urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('edit/', include((edit_url,'edit'))),
    path('create/', include((create_url, 'create'))),
]
```

---

```
# templates/accounts/index.html
{% url 'accounts:index' %}<br/>
{% url 'accounts:edit:index' %}<br/>
{% url 'accounts:create:index' %}<br/>

# on the website
/accounts/
/accounts/edit/index/
/accounts/create/index/
```

I hope this helps you. Have fun!

Comment: I missed the fact that the include had to be a tuple. Thank you :)